# XML/XSD to JSON'y format

Tags: xml, xsd

A Client asked me produce a textual representation of an XSD schema. The client said that they usually recieve this, along side the XSD's.
The format is as follows:

```
* ParentNode *
1{
      * ChildOneNode *
      [
             * PetNode *
             [
                   PetName
                   PetAge
             ]
             ChildName
             ChildAge
             * Toy *
             0{
                   ToyType
             }
             * Shoes *
             [
                   ShoeBrand
                   ShoeSize
                   (NumberOfVelcroBands)

             ]
             (ChildBestFriend)
      ]
}
```

Do any of you know this format. If yes, how can it be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this particular representation but there are lots of other simple hierarchic representations of a schema, and the problem of course is that (a) they tend to be underspecified, and (b) they're not very good at handling some of the trickier things you find in real schemas such as recursive types, model groups, attribute groups, and substitution groups, etc. So the first thing you need is a more precise specification of the notation, and advice on what to do when the thing in your schema isn't representable using that notation.

In general I would advise against trying to process source XSD documents directly. Use a schema processor that turns the XSD documents into a schema component model that provides an API you can use, and then access the data using that API. Xerces for example provides a Java API, while Saxon provides two ways of getting at the compiled schema component model: you can export it as an SCM file (in an XML representation), or you can navigate it using a set of extension functions in XPath.

It would also be worth asking the client whether the RelaxNG representation of the schema meets their needs. It's certainly a lot easier to generate, and at least as readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  looks rather bulky. I think they want something that is easily readable, and without too much syntactic sugar. This extended JSON format they asked for fits both.

Comment: Not sure I see any resemblance between this syntax and JSON.